# Commands in GWBASIC

Tags: list, save, gw-basic

I am using GWBASIC and cannot figure out a few things. Like, when I'm saving a program after running it with F4, it says: `File not found`.

Secondly, when I'm using auto command it shows `*` with line numbers.

Finally, if I want to take program and its output's print on paper, what should I do?

Comment: What is the exact text you are typing to try to save the program? Please separate out the multiple questions into separate questions as that makes it easier for them to be answered.

Comment: SO is a *question and answer* site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural (it's not *questionS*. You've asked three separate questions, which should each be asked in a separate post. In addition, all three of them are lacking in information. For instance, we can't tell you why you're getting *File not found*, because we don't know anything about how you're *saving a program after running it with F4*. You may want to review the [help] pages, especially [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 2):

> I am using GWBASIC and cannot figure out a few things. Like, when I'm
>   saving a program after running it with F4, it says: File not found.

Try saving like this:

```
SAVE"myprog.bas",a
```

> Secondly, when I'm using auto command it shows * with line numbers.

The star (*) on a line means that line already exists and you are overwriting it.
If you use the command NEW to wipe-out the program from memory before running 'auto', you won't see those stars on lines.

> Finally, if I want to take program and its output's print on paper,
>   what should I do?

1) Save the program as a text file:

```
SAVE"myprog.bas",a
```

2) Open the file 'myprog.bas' with a text editor (like Notepad++).

3) Print it.

Answer (score 2):

To print a GW-BASIC program, use the `LIST` command.

The optional `, filename` parameter specifies the output for the listing.  It could be to a file (e.g. to dump the text so another program can load it), or it could be to a printer device (e.g. `LPT1:`).

So this should work:

```
LIST ,LPT1:
```

See also https://robhagemans.github.io/pcbasic/doc/1.2/#LIST

Comment: If the target is `LPT1:` it's also possible to use just `LLIST` where that device is implicit.